# MultipartFormDataContent Access to path xx is denied

Tags: c#, api, file-upload, filestream

So I'm trying to upload a pdf file to a restapi. For some reason I the application cant get access to the files on my pc.

The code im using to upload:

```
public void Upload(string token, string FileName, string FileLocation, string Name, int TypeId, int AddressId, string CompanyName, string StreetNr, string Zip, string City, string CountryCode, string CustomFieldName, string CustomFieldValue)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = _API.baseAddress;
                //upload a new form
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTime.Now;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token);

                using (var multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent()) 
                {
                    //get te bytes from a file
                    byte[] pdfData;
                    using (var pdf = new FileStream(@FileLocation, FileMode.Open))//Here i get the error.
                    {
                        pdfData = new byte[pdf.Length];
                        pdf.Read(pdfData, 0, (int)pdf.Length);
                    }
                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(pdfData);
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = FileName + ".pdf"
                    };

                    //add the bytes to the multipart message
                    multiPartContent.Add(fileContent);

                    //make a json message
                    var json = new FormRest
                    {
                        Name = Name,
                        TypeId = TypeId,
                        AddressId = AddressId,
                        CompanyName = CompanyName,
                        StreetNr = StreetNr,
                        Zip = Zip,
                        City = City,
                        CountryCode = CountryCode,
                        CustomFields = new List<CustomFieldRest>
                            {
                                new CustomFieldRest {Name = CustomFieldName, Value = CustomFieldValue}
                            }
                    };
                    var Content = new JsonContent(json);

                    //add the json message to the multipart message
                    multiPartContent.Add(Content);

                    var result = client.PostAsync("forms", multiPartContent).Result;
                }

            }
        }
```

EDIT:

It seems to work for local files now. The problem is that i also have to upload files from a network share. How would i allow the application to access the files located on the domain share?

Comment: You must grant the executing user read rights to the files or elevate the applications privilages.

Comment: What's the value of `FileLocation`? Most locations will have security permissions to prevent your application accessing them.

Comment: @greg84 Well i tryed different locations like from a usb, my documents or straight from the c:\ drive. Same error every time.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen The user that runs the application got r/w access. Even running application as administrator does not work.

Comment: Is the path correct? What does `File.Exists` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The share that i tryed to connect to was hidden so i had to use $ at the end like this:

> \192.168.1.5\Testshare$\files

Answer (score 1):

If `FileLocation` is the path to the folder where the file is located your code should look something like this:

```
using (var pdf = new FileStream(Path.Combine(FileLocation, FileName + ".pdf"), FileMode.Open))
{
  pdfData = new byte[pdf.Length];
  pdf.Read(pdfData, 0, (int)pdf.Length);
}
```

I'd probably use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) instead:

```
var pdfData = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(FileLocation, FileName + ".pdf"));
```

Comment: I still get the error telling me i have no access to the location. Locally it works fine now but not for network shares.